# Python: How do I multiply and sum elements across two lists (without using a library)?

Tags: python, list

I've two lists (m1 and m2) containing lists of numbers. I'm trying to do element-wise multiplication and sum including the cross product to obtaining a final list (result) as follow:

```
m1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
m2 = [[7, 9, 2], [8, 1, 3]]

[[1*7+2*9+3*2,1*8+2*1+3*3],[4*7+5*9+6*2,4*8+5*1+6*3]]

result = [[31,19],[85,55]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play with python [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) and a nested list comprehension :

```
>>> [[sum(t*k for t,k in zip(i,j)) for j in m2] for i in m1]
[[31, 19], [85, 55]]
```

You can also use `itertools.product` to find the products between sub-lists :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [sum(t*k for t,k in zip(i,j)) for i,j in product(m1,m2)]
[31, 19, 85, 55]
```

Comment: the first solution works fine, the second one it is not in line with the format of the list "result". How to do it without importing any library?

Answer (score 5):

Let's break the problem into the smaller pieces. At the lowest level, we have two small lists: `[1, 2, 3]` and `[7, 9, 2]` and want to multiply them, item by item:

```
item1 = [1, 2, 3]
item2 = [7, 9, 2]
zip(item1, item2)                        # ==> [(1, 7), (2, 9), (3, 2)]
[x * y for x, y in zip(item1, item2)]    # ==> [7, 18, 6]
sum(x * y for x, y in zip(item1, item2)) # ==> 31
```

Now, we can put this to work inside a double loop:

```
[[sum(x * y for x, y in zip(item1, item2)) for item2 in m2] for item1 in m1]
# ==> [[31, 19], [85, 55]]
```

Comment: This works and it helps me a lot to understand. Thank you for your clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it without importing any modules, you can do it this way:

```
>>> m1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> m2 = [[7, 9, 2], [8, 1, 3]]
>>> [[sum(map(lambda (s,t):s*t, zip(x,y))) for y in m2] for x in m1]
[[31, 19], [85, 55]]
```